# How can I drop a mongo collection in Erlang with the mongodb-erlang driver?

Tags: mongodb, erlang

How can I drop a MongoDB collection in Erlang using the mongodb-erlang driver (https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-erlang)?

I didn't find anything in the docs: http://api.mongodb.org/erlang/mongodb/

I'm writing tests that create collections with different names and I want to drop them when the tests are finished. I can delete all the documents in a collection, but I want to drop the collection itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the mongo_query:command/3 function and the document form of the drop command:

```
1> mongo_query:command({Db, Conn}, {drop, 'foo.bar.baz'}, false).
{nIndexesWas,1.0,msg,<<"indexes dropped for collection">>,
ns,<<"foo.bar.baz">>,
ok,1.0}
```

Takes a regular connection, not a replset connection.

mongo_query:command/3 function:
http://api.mongodb.org/erlang/mongodb/mongo_query.html#command-3

Document form of MongoDB drop command function:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/drop/#dbcmd.drop